# React/Redux passing input values to the reducer.js

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Currently I have my application work with React alone and its state, I am trying to implement it with Redux.

I have a parent component which renders a child component, this child component is where I keep my input fields. And below is what I'm passing in to it (all working with the state and only `submitresults` works with the reducer).

```
            <ManualInputs
                //addEntry={this.addEntry}
                submitResults={this.props.submitResults}

                xPartyinputValue={this.props.xPartyinputValue}
                zPartyinputValue={this.props.zPartyinputValue}
                yActioninputValue={this.props.yAction}

                handleChangeAmount = {this.handleChangeAmount}
                handleChangeXParty={this.handleChangeXParty}
                handleChangeZParty={this.handleChangeZParty}
                handleChangeyAction={this.handleChangeyAction}
            />
```

The `submitResults={this.props.submitResults}` does work by sending an object to the reducer and I'll you below how it's working:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        submitResults: () => dispatch({type: 'SUBMIT', x: {
            id: Math.random(),
            xParty: 'Tom',
            yAction: 'Funds',
            zParty: 'Elizbath',
            amount: 50,
            payload: 'xPartyinputValue'
        }
        })
    };
};
```

The function above send data to the reducer.js file and update the initial state there correctly but my question is this,

Right now in the `submitResults` I am hard coding in values but I want to get the values from the users' input that's in `<ManualInputs>`. How do I do this?

----------------------- ***UPDATED AND FINISHED*** --------------------------

The only parts that have changed are `submitResults={this.props.submitResults}` into:

`submitResults={() => this.props.submitResults(this.state.xPartyinputValue, 
                            this.state.zPartyinputValue,
                            this.state.yActioninputvalue,
                            this.state.amountinputvalue)}`

This is not passing in the values we need.

And the `mapDispatchToProps` part is a but different, just passed in the args and called them.
`submitResults: (xParty, zParty, yAction, amount) => dispatch({type: 'SUBMIT', x: {
            id: Math.random(),
            xParty: xParty,
            yAction: zParty,
            zParty: yAction,
            amount: amount
        }
        })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can pass arguments to submitResults method...

consider the following code:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
return {
    submitResults: (args) => dispatch({type: 'SUBMIT', x: {
        id: Math.random(),
        xParty: args.xparty,
        yAction: args.yaction,
        zParty: args.zparty,
        amount: args.amount,
        payload: args.xpartyinputvalue
    }
    })
  };
};
```

Comment: Ah okay, that's a good idea but how will I go about calling the `submitResults` in the `<ManualInputs` ?. I have `  submitResults={() => this.props.submitResults(this.state.transactionInputs)}
` but I am just getting undefined returned.

Comment: can you provide a repo? or something where i can reproduce your scenario

Comment: Unfortunately I do not. Off the top of your head, how would you about passing the `(args)` from another component?  Like I have `submitResults={() => this.props.submitResults(this.state.transactionInputs)}` I feel like this is very close

Comment: I got it working, thanks for your guidance!, I have the updated version showing how it works if you're curious.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways.

1. You can use the `redux-form` to track your inputs and update state.
2. You can set your inputs to trigger actions and update appropriate fields inside your redux state. Then when you want to submit, you can just trigger a new action that gets your current state with `getState` (without going back to component) submits the data and on success clears your input fields.
3. You can set the local state inside your class component where your input fields are. Then in your `mapDispatchToProps` you can send the data to your already created action.

You can have a look at this guide to practice a bit: https://medium.com/@pnpsegonne/tutorial-creating-a-form-with-react-redux-c1b3025cf26b

It uses a couple of old react lifecycle functions but it will give you a good base on how stuff works.

Here you can read a bit more about `redux-form` and should you go that way: https://medium.com/dailyjs/why-build-your-forms-with-redux-form-bcacbedc9e8

Comment: Oh wow, so there's a few good options. Hmm what do you think is best looking into? I'm new to React and Redux, so maybe something that's quite straight forward?

Comment: Well option 3 is probably the easiest for you since you have most of it created already. All you have to do is create handle input functions to update the local state. One input > one local state param. Then you can send all of them to your action and set them back to empty strings.

Once that works. I would chose 1 or 2 and do it that way to for learning purposes. Because you will need it in the future :)

Comment: I already have the handleChanges which is a good start! I'm not exactly sure how I can send them into the `submitResults`? hmm I have something like this  `return {
  submitResults: (args) => dispatch({type: 'SUBMIT', x: {
   id: Math.random(),
   xParty: args.xParty,
   yAction: args.yAction,
   zParty: args.zParty,
   amount: 50
  }
  })
 };`

I think this might be okay above because it's not crashing but I am getting undefined for each field. 

I do have `submitResults={() => this.props.submitResults(this.state.transactionInputs)}
` to read it but its not getting the correct

Comment: I'm not sure of your exact structure so the answer is a bit on the general side. You can use `mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps)` to get the component props inside it. You might have to do some state moving around to get things to work. Also have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53149856/how-to-access-state-from-inside-mapdispatchtoprops